# Nodemailer attach a pdf make with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm using `https://github.com/devongovett/node-wkhtmltopd` to make pdf. The problem is that the mail arrives, but with a pdf with 0 bytes. The pdf generated in `out.pdf` is displayed correctly, so the problem lies at the time of attaching. I create a variable `ReadWriteStream` and then the `ReadStream` because only that data type accepts the nodemailer for attachments.

```
async main() {
    const pdf = wkhtmltopdf('<h1>Test</h1><p>Hello world</p>')
                     .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf'));

   const content = fs.createReadStream('out.pdf');

   await mailer.sendMail({
       from: "sender@server.com",
       to: "receiver@sender.com",
       subject: 'Title',
       text: 'Email body',
       attachments: [{
           filename: 'out.pdf',
           content: content,
       }]
   })
}
```

Comment: You probably need to open the file not create a stream with it. createReadStream is async and you don't have a content when you try to send an email.

Comment: @MehmetAli Do you have an example? to understand it better

Comment: You are right. Thanks